# assets:precompile connects to DB when initialize_on_precompile is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

I have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in my `config/application.rb` and `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` still attempts to connect to my DB. I changed my db name in `database.yml` to a non-existent database so I can tell when it's trying to connect.

```
$ be rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
FATAL:  database "aaa" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Heroku, this config is only available in Rails 3.x.
You can also see here in rails/rails repo on Rails 4 that the config for assets isn't there anymore:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb

For quick assets compiling, I use a simple sqlite3 config in production. It always connects no matter what. Your database.yml file should not be taken as is from your repo in production anyway. Either you use Heroku or a simple capistrano symlink to your shared folder, or any other custom solution.

Comment: `initialize_on_precompile` is documented in the Rails 4 guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets  I don't care so much about asset compilation speed, I just think it doesn't make sense to have to connect to the database to compile my assets.

Comment: Your quick on the downvote.. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb

Comment: It's been removed lately from the docs. Just hasn't been updated yet. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2d5a6de4e227ee97ccbea691c69728b7e31bf678

Comment: that's works for me https://iprog.com/posting/2013/07/errors-when-precompiling-assets-in-rails-4-0