# Heroku ignores public/assets/manifest-*.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

After running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and pushing to heroku, I get this error:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The complete log is here: http://dpaste.com/hold/1503531/

How can this happen when I have a `public/assets/manifest-*.json` file checked in? I'm using Rails 4.0.2.

In my `production.rb` I have:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733593/rails-4-heroku-doesnt-recognize-precompiled-manifest-fingerprint-json . Though I can't make heads or tails of his/her solution in the linked thread.

Comment: I saw that question, too. I couldn't understand the solution either.

Comment: Do you get the error while pushing to Heroku, or afterwards? If it's while pushing, could you show us the full push log?

Comment: @janfoeh I get the error while pushing. Here's the complete log: http://dpaste.com/hold/1503531/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue! I added an empty `public/assets/manifest.yml` file and pushed to heroku, and it no longer attempted the precompile while pushing.

```
Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

Comment: Good catch. The :assets group does not exist anymore in Rails 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile

Comment: @janfoeh that change didn't solve it actually. I've updated my answer - it seems like heroku is still relying on the presence of `public/assets/manifest.yml` even though it's deprecated in rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

`gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'`

this [issue](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111) is fixed in version 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in `config/application.rb` to prevent asset compilation from initializing a full Rails instance. If that is left unset, the Rails instance will be instantiated and try to start like normal, trying to connect to your database.

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

This is mentioned in the red alert box under [Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) and in bold just before it says, "Heroku requires this to be false.".

Comment: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` is no longer around in Rails 4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20008359/173630 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb

Comment: The setting won't be removed until 4.1 according to the commit message: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2d5a6de4e227ee97ccbea691c69728b7e31bf678#diff-19128a84fe2ae7019ccdb86efc86f684 Is there an equivalent in Rails 4?